# Rotational mechanics collision problem of a rod and body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

Smooth ball of mass 
m
moving with a uniform velocity 
0
v
strikes a 
smooth uniform rod AB of equal mass
m
, lying on a frictionless 
horizontal table. The ball strikes the rod at the end A, perpendicular to 
the rod, as shown in the figure. The collision is perfectly elastic   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu4V5.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Dear fitjee student show your working !